# Implementing Click Event Under Another Click Event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be fairly easy but I can't get my head around it. I have googled but can't find answers. I want to be able to capture some data when `button A` is clicked and submit those data when `button B` is clicked, via AJAX.

I have been thinking of this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button-a', function(){
    var captureData = $('available-data').text();

    $(document).on('click', 'button-b', function(){
        submitData(captureData);
    })
})
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check your selectors!

Comment: @Wilmer: I don't get you. Which of the selector?

Comment: All of them, check the jquery docs.

Comment: May be the best way to check about it is to set var captureData = undefined and see that undefined is passed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `captureData` globally. When you click on button-a the capture the value to `captureData` and when you click on button-b then submit it. You should not include button b click event inside button-a click event.

```
var captureData = 'default value';
$(document).on('click', 'button-a', function(){
    captureData = $('available-data').text();
});
$(document).on('click', 'button-b', function(){
    submitData(captureData);
});
```